# Is there any historical basis for King Suro being illustrated with a branching crown?

Tags: korea

[King Suro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suro_of_Geumgwan_Gaya) of Gaya is often depicted with a multi branching crown, but I can find no factual, historical reason for this. The crown his Queen Heo is depicted with is historically accurate, but the other Gaya crown found (presumably for the King) had an antler design, not a branching design.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

The bearded figure is King Suro. I do not know the provenance or authority of that illustration. The crown in the modern recreation of King Suro (as pictured) is clearly based on that illustration.

It differs significantly from the antler crown found in the tombs, as pictured. This discrepancy is unlike the Queen's floral crown (the unbearded figure), as photographed, and as in the illustration and modern statue and recreation.

Is there any historical accuracy in that branching crown of King Suro? Any written description or find on which it is based, or is it just an exercise in artistic license?

(Additional info: [Crown of Gaya](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_of_Gaya))

Comment: What are these images of? Which is the one(s) you are asking about? Which are comparisons to be considered? What is the provenance and authority of the images? of the images?

Comment: @johan88 please move that into.